# Unable to get the DisplayName of feature using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

I am trying to get the names of all the features available at site collection using CSOM. Below code works fine to get list of all the Features but i am unable to get the `DisplayName` property.

```
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(URL);
            Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(oWebsite, website => website.MasterUrl, website => website.CustomMasterUrl, website => website.Features);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Authenticated!");
            Console.ForegroundColor = defaultForeground;

            var webFeatures = clientContext.Web.Features;
            clientContext.Load(webFeatures, fcol => fcol.Include( f => f.DefinitionId));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var f in webFeatures)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f.DefinitionId);
            }
```

Here is a [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129443/getting-sharepoint-feature-properties-programatically-using-csom-in-sharepoint-o) that explains how to get the `DisplayName` but its not working for me.

I have upgraded the SDK for SP2013 but still i am unable to find this property. Can you please let me know if this is at all possible?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Any resolution @Ishan ?

Comment: @Karthik its available only for v16

Answer (score 0):

[`Feature.DisplayName property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.feature.displayname.aspx) is not accessible since you are not requesting it from the server, replace the line:

```
clientContext.Load(webFeatures, fcol => fcol.Include(f => f.DefinitionId));
```

with:

```
clientContext.Load(webFeatures, fcol => fcol.Include(f => f.DisplayName,f => f.DefinitionId));
```

> The expression `fcol.Include(f => f.DisplayName,f => f.DefinitionId)`
>   constructs the query for getting [features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.featurecollection.aspx) with
>   `Feature.DefinitionId` and `Feature.DisplayName` properties included.

**Example**

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{
    var webFeatures = ctx.Web.Features;
    ctx.Load(webFeatures, fcol => fcol.Include(f => f.DisplayName,f => f.DefinitionId));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**Update**

- If you are targeting SharePoint **2010**, then `Feature.DisplayName    property` could not be retrieved via CSOM API since [`Feature Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.feature(v=office.14).aspx) does not expose it.
- For SharePoint **2013** make sure [CSOM library `v15` is referenced](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)
- For SharePoint **Online** make sure [CSOM library `v16` is referenced](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Comment: Thanks Vadim. I had already tried that out, missed to include it in my question. The moment i include `f => f.DisplayName` , error is shown.

Comment: Error message : `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureCollection,object>>[]' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: @Ishan, it seems you are referencing CSOM v14 library in your project (see update section for a more details).  Since the question has been tagged `SharePoint 2013`, please make sure  CSOM library **v15** is referenced

Comment: I too felt the same initially so i downloaded CSOM v15 again, it asked for Repair option which meant i already had v15 library installed on my machine.

Comment: I am using v16 and connecting to sp2016. Getting error for include keyword. can you please let me know what namespace i need to include in order to fix the error. ERROR MESSAGE: 'FeatureCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'FeatureCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, it seems it just not possible for SP 2013 CSOM (v15), because even in the latest (currently) library Microsoft.SharePoint.CLient.dll 15.0.5127.1000 (from 4.2019 CU) this property is not available. despite in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/dn760908%28v%3Doffice.15%29?source=docs) mentioned that it's there.